# Alternate database for WSO2 MI Dashboard

Tags: mysql, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator

I've been trying to connect my wso2 mi dashboard to a MySQL database using the following documentation: https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.0.0/install-and-setup/install/installing-the-product/setting-up-mysql/

I've done the same for my micro-integrator server successfully, but when I try to do the same for the dashboard, it doesn't connect and continues to use the default h2 db.
I've followed all the steps in the document I've linked above, so if someone could point out where I'm going wrong that would be nice. Thanks!

Note: I've even updated my dashboard version to 4.1.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation [Installing the Micro Integrator Dashboard](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.0.0/install-and-setup/install/installing-the-product/installing-mi-dashboard/), this feature is available from **U2 level 17** onwards (wso2mi-dashboard 4.0.1.17.full). If you have a WSO2 subscription you can get it as an update for wso2mi-dashboard. For more information on WSO2 subscription check https://wso2.com/subscription/

Comment: I downloaded dashboard 4.1, and it still doesn't get connected, nor the proxy services updated in the sql db...

Comment: @ahinsa, This was only added for Dashboard 4.0.1, MI Dashboard 4.1 doesn't have the option to configure an external database, it uses the default H2 DB.

Comment: Thank you so, so much for the clarifications! It works now.
I just noticed that the dashboard only opens in incognito once I added the db configurations; in the main browser window it does not allow me to sign in. Any idea why? @sanoJ

Comment: Did you give it a try after clearing the cookies/cache in the main browser?

Comment: I did and it wasn't working; but then I closed all the dashboard tabs I had open and relaunched chrome and it's all good now.
Thanks so much again :)